# How to use Bootstrap button-group and AngularJS to navigate between pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this portion of code that creates a button group:

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
    <button id = "Image" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click1</button>
    <button id = "Text" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Click2</button>
</div>
```

I want to make it dynamic, in a sense that each button will take me to a different URL. I have come across this post:

[How do I navigate to another page on button click with Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230981/how-do-i-navigate-to-another-page-on-button-click-with-twitter-bootstrap)

However, I cannot use `<a></a>`  when dealing with a button group (or at least cannot think of a way to do so). So I guess I need a JS file with a function? How do I do that with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Javascript function such as:

```
go(path) {
    window.location = path;
}
```

Then call it from your button with:

```
ng-click="go('index.html')"
```

Comment: I have defined the entire html as an angularjs application. Is that not a problem? Can I still use basic html commands? I am asking this because on-click shows as undefined. Might be the angular definition, or might be because it is inside a bootstrap button? Not really sure since I am pretty new to all this.